# Redirecting a dynamic route in Flask to a new route to show a result in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've made a game of rock, paper, scissors based on a path to localhost i.e i'm using my machine as a dynamic web server with Flask.

My game logic is correct, has been tested and so when I type `http://localhost:5000/rock/paper` into my browser the following string is returned in the browser window:

```
Player 1 chose: Rock Player 2 chose: Paper So, the winner is...Player 2
```

However, I wish to change the route of these results to another new path called result using a result.html template. I.e I probably need something like `@app.route('/result')` somewhere to define the new route. For now I will likely have to retain the `/rock/paper` route also as that is my current means of data input to determine game results.

The code for my current dynamic path is as follows - I have a game class which takes 2 players and a player class which defines a player with a choice of rock/paper or scissors:

```
@app.route('/<choice_1>/<choice_2>')
def play_the_game(choice_1, choice_2):
    player_1 = Player("Player 1", choice_1)
    player_2 = Player("Player 2", choice_2)
    game = Game(player_1, player_2)
    winner = game.play_game()
    return "Player 1 chose: " + choice_1.title() + " " + " Player 2 chose: " + choice_2.title() + "    " + " So, the winner is..." + winner
```

But routing the result to a new template isn't as straight forward as:

```
@app.route('/result') = @app.route('/<choice_1>/<choice_2>')
```

FYI My HTML for the results.html file is incomplete and as follows. Note: I have a base.html file which this file extends into:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div>
    <p>Game Results here:</p>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just render_template with the value of the winner

```
@app.route('/<choice_1>/<choice_2>')
def play_the_game(choice_1, choice_2):
    player_1 = Player("Player 1", choice_1)
    player_2 = Player("Player 2", choice_2)
    game = Game(player_1, player_2)
    winner = game.play_game()
    return render_template("result.html", winner = winner)
```

With this , we are passing the value of the variable "winner" , to the HTML page .

Your result.html should look something like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div>
    <p>Game Results here:</p>
    <h2>  {{ winner }} </h2>

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

The Jinja Template Engine automatically fills in the value for the variables between {{  }}

Comment: Can I ask why we had to define winner = winner in return render_template("result.html", winner = winner)? Why is another assignment required in order to pass to the result.html template? I thought we could just do return render_template("result.html", winner). Thank you as I believe this fixed my issue!

Comment: I am sorry if the naming of my variables was not clear . We could name the variables anything . But we have to name the 1st variable in `winner = winner` and the variable in the HTML the same . You could watch this for more details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQrq207zXzU